# How to replace this if/else statement with bitwise operations?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am doing bitwise & between two bit arrays saving the result in old_array and I want to get rid of the if/else statement. I should probably make use of the BIT_STATE macro, but how?

```
#define BYTE_POS(pos) (pos / CHAR_BIT)
#define BIT_POS(pos) (1 << (CHAR_BIT - 1 - (pos % CHAR_BIT)))
#define BIT_STATE(pos, state) (state << (CHAR_BIT - 1 - (pos % CHAR_BIT)))

if (((old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)] & BIT_POS(old_pos)) != 0) && 
   ((new_array[BYTE_POS(new_pos)] & BIT_POS(new_pos)) != 0))
{
   old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)] |= BIT_POS(old_pos);
}
else
{
      old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)] &= ~(BIT_POS(old_pos));
}
```

Comment: It would help enourmously if you would simplify your code to the relevant bits. For instance, is it relevant that you have `old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)]`? Can’t you just use `x`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bit operation instead of if for copying bit maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829544/bit-operation-instead-of-if-for-copying-bit-maps)

Answer (score 2):

You can always calculate both results and then combine it. The biggest problem is to compute a fitting bitmask.

E.g.

```
const uint32_t a = 41,
      uint32_t b = 8;

const uint32_t mask[2] = { 0, 0xffffffff };

const uint32_t result = (a&mask[condition])
                      | (b&mask[!condition]);
```

or to avoid the unary not

```
const uint32_t mask_a[2] = { 0, 0xffffffff },
               mask_b[2] = { mask_a[1], mask_a[0] };

const uint32_t result = (a&mask_a[condition])
                      | (b&mask_b[condition]);
```

However: When doing bitwise manipulations, always be careful with the number of bits involved. One way to be careful is fixed size types like uint32_t, who may or may not be defined on your platform (but if not, the good thing is you get a compile error), or use templates carefully. Other types, including `char`, `int` and even `bool` can have any size beyond some defined minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such code looks somewhat ugly.
I don't think BIT_STATE is useful here. (State MUST BE 0 or 1 to work as expected)

I see following approaches to get rid of them

a) Use C++ bitfields

For example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

b) 
"Hide" that code in a class/method/function

c)
I think this is equivalent to your code

```
if ((new_array[BYTE_POS(new_pos)] & BIT_POS(new_pos)) == 0))
{
   old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)] &= ~(BIT_POS(old_pos));
}
```

or as inliner

```
   old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)] &= 
      ~((new_array[BYTE_POS(new_pos)] & BIT_POS(new_pos)) ? 0 : BIT_POS(old_pos));
```

Comment: Yes, that is a simplification of the if/else statement. Now I just need to get rid of that. Suggestions a-c) noted.

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of "if" oe "?:" without bitfields

Answer (score 0):

Take the expression

(new_array[BYTE_POS(new_pos)] & BIT_POS(new_pos))

which is either 0 or has 1 in bit BIT_POS(new_pos) and shift it until the bit, if set is in BIT_POS( old_pos )

(new_array[BYTE_POS(new_pos)] & BIT_POS(new_pos)) << ( old_pos - new_pos )

now and the result with old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)]

old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)] &= old_array[BYTE_POS(old_pos)]

THe only trick is that it is implementation dependent (at least it used to be) what happens if you shift by a negative amount.  So if you already know whether old_pos is greater or less than new_pos you can substitute >> ( new_pos - old_pos ) when appropriate.

I've not tried this out.  I may have << and >> swapped.